# How to convert Spring Integration XML to Java DSL for errorChannel

Tags: spring-integration

I have the below xml configuration in my application and I would like to convert it to the Java DSL.

So in this reference I'm explicitly defining the name for the error channel.  Mostly for example reason.  With this reference what I'm expecting to happen is when a downstream process throws and exception that it should route the payload back through the error channel.  What would the Java code look like?

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="notification" 
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        destination="otificationQueue" 
        channel="notificationChannel"
        error-channel="error"       
         />

<int:chain id="chainError" input-channel="error">
        <int:transformer id="transformerError" ref="errorTransformer" />
        <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
            id="error"
            connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
            destination="errorQueue" />
    </int:chain>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                        .id("notification")
                        .destination(this.notificationQueue)
                        .errorChannel(this.errorChannel))

                ...

                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow ErrorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(this.errorChannel)
                .transform(errorTransformer())
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                        .destination(this.errorQueue), e -> e.id("error"))
                .get();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

and autowire it, or reference it as

```
.errorChannel(errorChannel())
```

Comment: Stupid question I know but how is this.errorChannel defined?  Could you update the example to reflect this?

Comment: Gary in the xml configuration I don't have to define a Message Channel for the errorChannel.  Would it be possible for the DSL to behave the same way?  I would think that the .outputChannel on messageDriverChannelAdapter would also work the same way.

Comment: With XML, we auto-declare input channels if not present; it's not so easy with java. While you could use `.from(MessageChannels.direct("errors"))` on the error flow, which will auto declare the channel, we need a reference to a real channel in `.errorChannel(channel)`. You can't use `MessageChannels` again there because it would be a different channel. We could look at adding `.errorChannelName("errors")`, but that would need changes to the core framework (as well as the DSL). Feel free to open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) (JavaDSL component) and we can take a look.

Comment: I understand now thanks for the help.  You and @artem-bilan are both a big help.